# SQL copy column from a table into another table - unique

Tags: mysql, sql

basically I have to copy 2 columns from a specific table and add them into another table. Here is how I can do it :

```
Insert into biz_ctx_rule (from_biz_ctx_id, top_level_bie_id)
    select distinct biz_ctx_id, owner_top_level_abie_id
    FROM abie;
```

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '20-52' for key 'biz_ctx_rule_unicity'

The issue is that I added an unicity constraint on (from_biz_ctx_id, top_level_bie_id). 
Is there a simple way to do it with UNIQUE() or do I have to try some jointure ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '20-52' for key 'biz_ctx_rule_unicity'

Comment: Basically I cannot do that statement because of the unicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is inserting duplicates, then use `on duplicate key update`:

```
Insert into biz_ctx_rule (from_biz_ctx_id, top_level_bie_id)
    select distinct biz_ctx_id, owner_top_level_abie_id
    from abie
    on duplicate key update from_biz_ctx_id = values(from_biz_ctx_id);
```

The `update` is basically a no-op, but it prevents an error from being returned, so the `insert` succeeds.

Comment: It is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.